# I place two divs with text, then one with a photo and a last one with more text. But it seems the place taken up by the photo is ignored?

Tags: html, css

I got  problem. As I feel sure this is just me missing some important point, I have not made a detailed explanation, but just gone through what I actually did:

1. I write some text in a div.
2. I then write some more text in another size in another div.
3. I then write an image, also in a div. I set the width to 100% and set no height, which means I will get as large a picture as possible but still keep the relationship.
4. And I then end up writing some more text in a third size.
5. I now decide I need a button in the right side of the last div. I place it with a flow and it seems to work, only the vertical setting is a bit off.
6. I then decide to place the button in the vertical middle of the div, using this method: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_center-vertical
7. But now the buttons are not placed in the middle at all. Instead, they are placed way higher.

I fiddle around a bit and this is what I find out:

[image]

I gave each div and the foto a margin, and a different background color, the photo red and the last div pink.
As you can see, the browser ignores the div with the foto and instead starts its div where the second div stops.
As I understand it, this is not in compliance with the normal placing of the elements. I place the photo before I place the last div with its button, so why does the last div start before the photo?
And what am I missing and how do I fix it?

Hope there is someone with an answer out there

Best regards

Poul

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the HTML, CSS and other code that is pertinent.

Comment: I agree with SScotti, it's hard to help without seeing the actual code, both html and css.

Comment: I get your point and made an example including the css and code. That actually made me figure out the problem, just by deleting each line in the css one by one. So now it works, but I still don't understand why. So I plan to get back to the problem, but right now I am too busy. But I added a more detailed explanation together with the solution. Any ways, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Late addition:
The problem seems to be solved. I tried to make a simple example and when I’d done that it was quite easy to actually locate the offending css and/or code.
The italicized lines are removed from the working sample as are the entire class retFoto.
So now it works, but I still don’t understand why.

---

Here is a tighter demonstration:

[image]

My question is:
Since I place the different ’s as follows:

```
echo "<div class='retten'>";
echo "<div class='rettensNavn'>A name</div>";

echo "<div class='retbeskrivelse'> A text </div>";

echo "<div class='retFoto'>";
echo "  <img class='foto' src='1/1.png' alt='Some name'>";
echo "</div>";    

echo "<div class='Pris'>" . "Pris: 175,50 kr";
echo   "<button class='BestilKnap'>Bestil</button>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

should the Pris-div not start after the picture (The red one)?

As I understand it, a HTML and/or php-script always maintains a printing position, that moves when ever you place another element (and delete a node or something). If that is true, should the Pris-div not start after the picture?

This is the full code and css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link href="editerbare.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
  <?php
    echo "<div class='retten'>";

    echo "<div class='rettensNavn'>A name</div>";

    echo "<div class='retbeskrivelse'> A text </div>";

    echo "<div class='retFoto'>";
    echo "  <img class='foto' src='1/1.png' alt='Some name'>";
    echo "</div>";    

    echo "<div class='Pris'>" . "Pris: 175,50 kr";
    echo   "<button class='BestilKnap'>Bestil</button>";
    echo "</div>";    

    echo "</div>";    
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the css

```
.RestaurantOverskrift {
  font-family: Bahnschrift Semilight; /*Calibri;*/
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;

  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.RestaurantAdresse {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.GruppeOverskrift {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
}

.retten {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.rettensNavn {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
}

.retbeskrivelse {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

img.foto {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.retFoto {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.Pris {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.BestilKnap {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try add a class

```
.nomarginpadding {margin: 0 ;padding: 0 ;}
```

and wrap you price tag and button tag with column class then the button should be located at the next line middle part

Comment: `!important` will lead you into problems. I don't remember the last time I used one.